# How Magento Cron Job works

Tags: cron

Recently i was trying to extend the `Out Of Stock` product alert functionality.
For this i planned to use the cron Job, but i was un successful , i followed some links but nothing happens.

Is any one knows how magento performs its routine work. Like re-indexing, catalog price update, as i found that even no cron job is schedule at cpanel also.

```
-->Email (Transactional and any other email sent from the store.)
-->Catalog Price Rules
-->Newsletters
-->Customer Alerts and Notifications
-->Log Cleanup
```

Then how it works , for example , if i subscribe for out of stock feature( default) , it send me mail once product is back in stock.

Even in `cron_schedule` table last schedule is not up-to-date.
[image: last_cron]